# Formatting divs using Pandoc

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I am using Pandoc to convert Pandoc Markdown documents to HTML5 documents. In my md input, I write custom divs using a [special Pandoc syntax](http://www.pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans), for example :

```
::: Resources
A nice document
Informative website
:::
```

The resulted HTML is this :

```
<div class="Resources">
    <p>A nice document Informative website</p>
</div>
```

I would like the output to be something like this instead :

```
<div class="Resources">
    <div>A nice document</div>      
    <div>Informative website</div>
</div>
```

Ie. I want the two resources to be in two different containers. I did not find any solution to do that (it is possible that the [pandoc filters](http://www.pandoc.org/filters.html) can, but I don't quite understand how to write them).

Thank you very much for any kind of help. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the main goal is to have separate *Resource* blocks, I'd suggest to use a [list](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#bullet-lists) inside the div:

```
::: Resources
- A nice document
- Informative website
:::
```

This will give

```html
<div class="Resources">
<ul>
<li>A nice document</li>
<li>Informative website</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It's not what you want yet, but get's us half way there. It already marks all resources as separate blocks. This simplifies our task to refine the document structure further through filtering. The following uses pandoc's Lua filter functionality; put the code into a file and pass it to pandoc via the `--lua-filter` command line parameter.

```lua
local list_to_resources = {
  BulletList = function (el)
    local resources = {}
    local resource_attr = pandoc.Attr('', {'Resource'}, {})
    for i, item in ipairs(el.content) do
      resources[i] = pandoc.Div(item, resource_attr)
    end
    return resources
  end
}

function Div (el)
  -- return div unaltered unless it is of class "Resources"
  if not el.classes:includes'Resources' then
    return nil
  end
  return pandoc.walk_block(el, list_to_resources)
end
```

Calling pandoc with this filter will produce your desired output:

```html
<div class="Resources">
<div class="Resource">
A nice document
</div>
<div class="Resource">
Informative website
</div>
</div>
```

---

For the sake of completeness, I'll also add a solution to the question when taking it literally. However, I do not recommend using it for various reasons:

1. It is far less "markdowny". Using only linebreaks to separate items is uncommon in Markdown and goes against its philosophy of having readable text without surprises.
2. The necessary code is more complex and fragile.
3. You won't be able to add additional information to the *Resources* div, as it will always be mangeled-up by the filter. With the previous solution, only bullet lists have a special meaning.

That being said, here's the code:

```lua
-- table to collect elements in a line
local elements_in_line = {}

-- produce a span from the collected elements
local function line_as_span()
  local span = pandoc.Span(elements_in_line)
  elements_in_line = {}
  return span
end

local lines_to_blocks = {
  Inline = function (el)
    print(el.t)
    if el.t == 'SoftBreak' then
      return line_as_span()
    end
    table.insert(elements_in_line, el)
    return {}
  end,

  Para = function (el)
    local resources = {}
    local content = el.content
    -- last line is not followed by SoftBreak, add it here
    table.insert(content, line_as_span())
    local attr = pandoc.Attr('', {'Resource'})
    for i, line in ipairs(content) do
      resources[i] = pandoc.Div(pandoc.Plain(line.content), attr)
    end
    return resources
  end
}

function Div (el)
  -- return div unaltered unless it is of class "Resources"
  if not el.classes:includes'Resources' then
    return nil
  end
  return pandoc.walk_block(el, lines_to_blocks)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My goal is not not to have line-breaks, it is to have both resources (“A nice document” and “Informative website”) in separate HTML containers, like in my exemple. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the update, the question is clearer now. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: A **huge** thank you for this effort. I really appreciate both solutions, and the fact that you explained their pros and cons. I will implement it later this week.

Answer (score 0):

In https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans you mentionned, there is this sample :

```
::::: {#special .sidebar}
Here is a paragraph.

And another.
:::::
```

So just add a blank line between you two lines

```
::: Resources
A nice document

Informative website
:::
```

**Note** that it doesn't create sub-div but just paragraphs (<p>)

To create sub-divs :

```
::: Resources ::::::
::: subdiv1
A nice document
:::
::: subdiv1
Informative website
:::
::::::::::::::::::
```

**Note** that you should have a class name to your sub-divs, and it add <p> inside each div.

In my case, I use it to include a [w3-panel](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_panels.asp) div in a [w3-container](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_containers.asp) div